# How can I handle this kind of crash and it occurred when switching between two applications

Tags: xamarin.forms

[Create Proxy crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp0t2.png)

mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run
RunnableImplementor.java, line 30
Java.Interop.JavaLocationException: Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown

Comment: If that is all you have then all I can say is that somewhere in your code, I am not sure which page because the Stacktrace is not complete, You are making a change in the UI that is not on the UIThread!

Comment: I have attached an image of crash. Please go through it

Comment: I am aware even that is not complete, This looks like App centre though so you should have the Class name there in the subtitle